# How to add a class to a html element using filters in WordPress?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am changing the current theme of my blog and I wish to add a class to all my input fields.

I am not well versed with regex codes, so I end up in a lot of trouble whenever I need to make things like these happen.

### type="submit"

I want to add class `btn` needs to be added to `<input type="submit">`

**Old Code**

```
<input type="submit" id="some_id" name="something" class="some_class" value="some_value" />
```

**New Code**

```
<input type="submit" id="some_id" name="something" class="btn some_class" value="some_value" />
```

---

### and

Similarly, I want the class `input` to be added to `<input type="text">` and `<input type="textarea">`

**Old Code**

```
<input type="text" id="some_id" name="something" class="some_class" value="some_value" />
<textarea id="some_id" name="something" class="some_class" value="some_value" />
```

**New Code**

```
<input type="text" id="some_id" name="something" class="input some_class" value="some_value" />
<textarea id="some_id" name="something" class="input some_class" value="some_value" />
```

Comment: @thecodeparadox jQuery is the easiest solution for it. But I wish to use WP Hooks to do the job.

Comment: In what way do you want hooks to be involved in this. jQuery or CSS can be used to select these elements based on what you've shown, but are you talking about wanting to create your own hook, which would allow you do dynamically add classes to any element using that hook?

Comment: @eddiemoya You got me right there. Yes, I want to add classes to the elements dynamically.

Comment: regex is a little bit hard, I think xml do it better http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php

Comment: @benoît I am not sure about how do I use xml to get the job done.

Comment: I don't know if it's work but using xml parser on xhtml it's not stupid…
I found this : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Aniket when you have added the classes that you want, what are you going to do with it? Is it for use with CSS or do you have another purpose with it?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It's majorly for CSS. My theme has many types of styling for elements. I wanted to bring uniformity to them, by using a singular class with it. That is why the need for a **class** with them.

Comment: That's what jQuery is for, these forms are not default with WordPress so why would you expect there to be a function to alter them?

Comment: @Wyck Understood. So, jQuery is the cleanest and the most appropriate way to do it.

Comment: @Aniket - I respectfully disagree with the jQuery approach. While it would be EASY and require less code for you to write out by hand, you would have to include an entire Javascript framework (about 30KB worth) to do what is otherwise a fairly trivial task. If your theme depends on certain classes being in place for its stylesheet, then the server should handle it. There is a time and a place for jQuery, but my advice is that this is not it.

Comment: jQuery is included in WordPress by default..

Comment: Yes, included. But not enqueued by default. Using it for this PARTICULAR purpose is just bad practice. As mentioned, there is a time and a place for jQuery, I just personally don't find this scenario to be one of them.

Comment: @maiorano84 There are quite some thing that I need to do with jQuery and many plugins use it on my website. So, doing it via jQuery got no harm according to me.

Comment: And that's fine. It's just a personal belief of mine that one should only use jQuery to correct problems unique to jQuery. Applying classes to elements automatically for a stylesheet that already exists is not unique to jQuery or Javascript. And of course, not adhering to this convention 100% of the time won't necessarily cause you trouble either. However, using client-side languages too much can detract from your page's performance, so my only advice is to be careful, and use the right tools for the right jobs.

Comment: @maiorano84 Even I agree with what you think. That is very much true for client-side scripting. You can't trust it with a lot of responsibilities. But they sure do come to the rescue. Like they say - "Desperate Times, Desperate Measures".

Comment: I hear you there, my friend. If it's the difference between maintaining personal convention and putting food on the table, I'm always going to choose food. Because food is yummy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your constraints, the cleanest way you can do what you want with PHP and stay within the Wordpress framework is to use DOMDocument. While it's POSSIBLE to rely on regular expressions, it's very sloppy and you can run into more problems than what you started with.

Place this in your functions.php file, and it should do everything you need:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_text_input_classes', 20);
function add_text_input_classes($content)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); //Instantiate DOMDocument
    $doc->loadHTML($content); //Load the Post/Page Content as HTML
    $textareas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('textarea'); //Find all Textareas
    $inputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input'); //Find all Inputs
    foreach($textareas as $textarea)
    {
        append_attr_to_element($textarea, 'class', 'input');
    }
    foreach($inputs as $input)
    {
        $setClass = false;
        if($input->getAttribute('type') === 'submit') //Is the input of type submit?
            $setClass = 'btn';
        else if($input->getAttribute('type') === 'text') //Is the input of type text?
            $setClass = 'input';

        if($setClass)
            append_attr_to_element($input, 'class', $setClass);
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML(); //Return modified content as string
}
function append_attr_to_element(&$element, $attr, $value)
{
    if($element->hasAttribute($attr)) //If the element has the specified attribute
    {
        $attrs = explode(' ', $element->getAttribute($attr)); //Explode existing values
        if(!in_array($value, $attrs))
            $attrs[] = $value; //Append the new value
        $attrs = array_map('trim', array_filter($attrs)); //Clean existing values
        $element->setAttribute($attr, implode(' ', $attrs)); //Set cleaned attribute
    }
    else
        $element->setAttribute($attr, $value); //Set attribute
}
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, but the code sure is *sloppy*. I am going to use jQuery to the job. Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Well said about regular expressions. They shouldn't be used for something they're not designed for! (such as this).

Comment: This actually does nothing to solve the problem, his question was a bit vague. The elements he's talking about changing are not within the_content, they are in his templates and in widgets. There is no filter for this, he just needs to use some other CSS selectors or edit his theme.

Comment: @eddiemoya Anika had indicated in a comment (on your answer, I believe) that he wanted to hook into the_content. This example was based on that statement, and shows that there is always a much more effective way to parse HTML without Regex. For Widgets, he would want to add a filter of 'widget_text'. For his templates, he would have to add them by hand. So this DOES solve his problem as he indicated, in that he wanted to see a PHP-based example of how it would be done using filters.

Comment: I see, I thought he saw your solution and then asked it of me afterward. In any case, he later explains that his input fields are not part of posts, but are rather in the templates and widgets themselves. He could use widget_text if they were part of the content of the widgets, but I suspect they might just be elements baked into the code. No offense intended to @Aniket but he appears to have had a very misinformed understanding of what 'the_content' is and how hooks in general work.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to dynamically apply classes to input elements. What you need to use is a filter, or a series of filters.

First let me explain how filters work. Filters work with 'hooks' just like Actions. See the [Actions and Filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters) codex page for details.

It sounds like you want to use hooks to add this `btn` class without needing to manually change each input. Thats not how hooks work. To use hooks for this you would use filters, which would mean you would need to write...

```
<input type="submit" class="<?php echo apply_filters('input_class', 'some-default-class'); ?>" />
```

You would then be able to add a filter to the 'input_class' tag.

```
add_filter('input_class', 'btn_class_filter');

function btn_class_filter($default){
    return 'btn';
}
```

Whatever your function returns will replace the default value - in this case 'some-default-class' will be replaced with 'btn'.

However none of this eliminates the need to add code to each input field you want to add the class. The only way to do that, would be through javascript, most easily with jQuery. I know you said you didn't want to use jQuery, but if you dont want to edit markup, thats your only option.

The simplest thing to do would be to just add the `btn` class manually - if its a matter of access, the jQuery will be the way to go.

Comment: So it is not possible to create a regex replace function which will use `the_content()` and then make the changes for me?

Comment: Yes, if the input elements are in the post content, you could filter the_content and use regex to add the btn. You had not indicated above that the input fields were in posts. Is that the case?

Comment: The input fields are not in posts but rather coming from widgets and some form templates.

Comment: You cant do this without editing the templates and widgets unless you use jquery. Actions/Filters require a hook to be in place. I suggest you modify the templates to do what you need, and I would suggest you use jquery for the rest if those widgets are not your own. In the end, I don't understand why you actually need to add these classes. Textareas can be selected just by using "textarea" selector, and for submit buttons "input[type=submit]" will work, similarly text fields can be selected with "input[type=text]" . You dont need the . or # because css lets you select by element name.

Comment: Also, I should explain that the_content and its relevant filters only effect data that is in the content of a post, not templates or widgets. You are going to need to edit your templates and widgets, or just use smarter CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just applying blanket style rules to these elements and don't care about IE6 support, why not just use attribute selectors in your CSS, eg

```
.btn, input[type="submit"] {
    /* styles for buttons */
}

.input, input[type="text"], textarea {
    /* styles for text inputs and textareas */
}
```

FYI, there is no `<input type="textarea">`, just [`<textarea>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea)

To manipulate markup using a hook would be time consuming and clumsy. You'd need to grab all template output as well as plugin generated markup. I'd recommend not attempting this, Wordpress code is messy enough.

Comment: I am sorry for using `type="textarea"`. Should have used `<textarea>`. So even you do not recommend a PHP solution. Understood.

Answer (score -2):

I answered above, and I would simply edit that one but its already received votes, and this answer will be significantly different.

After some comments in my initial answer, I realized that the input fields @Aniket wants to change are not within the content, they are elements throughout the site, such as in widgets, and in the templates themselves.

There is no way through hooks, actions, or filters, to modify the code thats written within the theme templates. Filters can modify strings and values, but only if there is a hook already available to do so. You don't have this, so its not possible. Your only option for adding this class dynamically without editing the input fields is to use javascript. This however is pointless for two reasons.

1. It would be simpler to just edit the input fields themselves
2. You dont need to add these classes, because CSS lets you select those elements in other ways.

**You dont need to add an `'input'` class to input fields.**

CSS allows you to select elements by the tag name, so for example if you wanted to select any div, you dont need add a `".div"` class to every div. You can select all div's by simply using `"div"` without any class or ID notation.

The same applies to textareas. You said you wanted to add an `input` class to textareas, text fields, and submit buttons, but thats not necessary. You can select all those using [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). In this case, were going to specify input fields with the attribute submit, and text, as well as textarea elements stead of the two classes you wanted to add.

**Instead of adding a .btn class to submit buttons, use...**

```
input[type="submit"] {
   /* Your styles */
}
```

**And instead of adding an .input class to text fields and textareas use...**

```
textarea, input[type="text"] {
   /* Your styles */
}
```

**Alternatively, if you just want all input fields, not just text areas and text fields use...**

```
input {
   /* Your styles */
}
```

Even if you did this though javascript, you would end up having to select these elements using this kind of CSS selection anyway, and any regex you could possibly do would be significantly more complicated than these simple lines.

Comment: I know how CSS selectors work, but when you have four kinds of selectors styling the very same thing, then the better alternative is to go ahead and use classes with them, so that my processing time reduces.

Comment: Well you really dont have that option, and the reduction of processing time is not very much in fact it would be completely un measurable. Its a matter of very few characters involved. Any regex or hooks you might use would be vastly less performant than simply using CSS. This is what CSS is made to do after all. If you insist that you must add these classes, the only way to do so (especially if your worry is performance) is to edit the templates. Thats it, no way around those two - use better CSS, or edit your templates.

Comment: This is downvoted now because its not the answer you wanted, but its the correct answer. No, you cant use filters change the classes assigned to markup within templates. You must use smart CSS, or edit those templates.