# Add additional css classes to an existing HTML Element in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to eliminate a specific jQuery file from a custom theme (file.js). This file contained several scripts, which are no longer needed, due to the theme's customization. The only remaining script uses jQuery to add an additional CSS Class, to a HTML Element, based on a scroll event (scrollTop). The code looks like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1 ) {
          $('.site-header').addClass('shrink');
     } else {
          $('.site-header').removeClass('shrink');
     }
});
```

...and it modifies:

```
<header class="site-header" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
```

...to be:

```
<header class="site-header shrink" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
```

...when the end user has scrolled to the top of the page.

The scrollTop event is no longer needed, but I still need to add the .shrink class to the header element and I'd like to do it using PHP in WordPress' functions.php file.

WordPress Templates may contain multiple header html elements, so it is important to target only the header html element which also has the .site-header css class.

I've tried modifying the following code:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_text_input_classes', 20);
function add_text_input_classes($content)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); //Instantiate DOMDocument
    $doc->loadHTML($content); //Load the Post/Page Content as HTML
    $textareas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('textarea'); //Find all Textareas
    $inputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input'); //Find all Inputs
    foreach($textareas as $textarea)
    {
        append_attr_to_element($textarea, 'class', 'input');
    }
    foreach($inputs as $input)
    {
        $setClass = false;
        if($input->getAttribute('type') === 'submit') //Is the input of type submit?
            $setClass = 'btn';
        else if($input->getAttribute('type') === 'text') //Is the input of type text?
            $setClass = 'input';

        if($setClass)
            append_attr_to_element($input, 'class', $setClass);
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML(); //Return modified content as string
}
function append_attr_to_element(&$element, $attr, $value)
{
    if($element->hasAttribute($attr)) //If the element has the specified attribute
    {
        $attrs = explode(' ', $element->getAttribute($attr)); //Explode existing values
        if(!in_array($value, $attrs))
            $attrs[] = $value; //Append the new value
        $attrs = array_map('trim', array_filter($attrs)); //Clean existing values
        $element->setAttribute($attr, implode(' ', $attrs)); //Set cleaned attribute
    }
    else
        $element->setAttribute($attr, $value); //Set attribute
}
```

...provided by @maiorano84 here: [How to add a class to a html element using filters in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468697/how-to-add-a-class-to-a-html-element-using-filters-in-wordpress), to suit my needs, but cannot get it to work correctly.

Please help!

Comment: why not edit the theme file directly? what theme you are using? it might have some filter to add a class on some element

Comment: It is a highly customized variation of the Centric Pro, Genesis Child theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using genesis, you don't need a very complicated code to modify HTML output, simply add a filter to the site-header prefix, genesis is by far the most customizable framework.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_site-header', 'my_custom_genesis_header_class' );
function my_custom_genesis_header_class( $attributes ) {
    $attributes['class'] .= ' shrink';
    return $attributes;
}
```

Comment: I use Genesis almost exclusively, but could not find this filter. Since I've already got egg on my face, could you point me to where you found it?

Comment: All my wordpress works also uses genesis :) you would need a login details to access the docs https://my.studiopress.com/docs/filter-reference/

though I found some doing quick google search https://wpbeaches.com/adding-attribute-html-section-genesis/

Comment: I have a shortcut to the StudioPress Filter Reference (complete with login), but still do not see it in there, though it's pretty easy to find on the second link you provided.

Stupid follow-up question: Would the Genesis filter structure interfere (or prevent) the PHP DOMDocument Function(s) from working correctly?

Comment: can't remember exactly the specific sections for all the filters, I've memorized most (might even all) of genesis filters and hooks as I've dealt with it almost everyday. For your question, I can't really confirm about that, what matters is which filter runs last, Also, I believe the reason your previous code doesn't work is because you are passing the filter on ```the_content``` which never generates the header HTML elements.